# How do I email everyone in a meeting invitation in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When I'm in a meeting, I often want to email something to everyone on the call.  Through Outlook, if I open up the meeting in my calendar and select **File -> New -> Mail Message** it opens up an untitled mail message and the **To...** and **Subject:** fields are blank.  Is there an easy way to open up a new message to everyone invited to the meeting (everyone listed in the Scheduling tab)?  The list of invitees can get pretty long.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Find the event in your calendar. Right click on the calendar entry and there should be a 'Reply All' option. It's greyed out in my screen capture because I don't have anyone else invited to the appointment, but it illustrates the answer...

[image]

Comment: Awesome, that works even better.

Answer (score 6):

For Outlook 2013...

If you have the meeting item opened, you can go to the Meeting menu and click Respond to find Reply All...

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I found it under the Actions menu of the appointment, Reply to All with Message.

[image: Outlook Actions menu]

You may have to expand the Actions menu as I did in order to see this option.